# People trying SQL Injection attacks on our servers

Tags: sql, security, sql-injection

I am a developer for a company that has numerous clients.  I protect against SQL Injection multiple ways.

1. By using Parameterized queries
2. By using Stored procedures for every interaction with the database
3. By using validation on the server to ensure data is of correct type
4. Delete/Insert/Update permission is denied at table level for user of the websites (the website user role is only allowed execute permission on the procedures that are ran through the website)

I log all of the injection attacks, with attempted attack info, date, ip address, useragent.   Some days there are a lot of them.  Today is one of those days.  In the last hour I have logged over 10,000 such attacks, and they are still coming in at a rate of about 150 or so per minute.   Typically the attacks come in on the few pages where a parameter is passed in the query string.  So my validation then sees it is a potential attack and logs it then sends a 400 status to the browser.   Today I saw something different and am curious what they are trying to hit  this does not look like a Transact SQL   in this instance the information after the 778 is the data added to the query string

```
778";CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SLEEP(int) RETURNS int AS '/lib/libc.so.6','sleep' language 'C' STRICT; SELECT sleep(32) AND "fvtz" LIKE "fvtz
```

is this a Linux mySQL attack or ??

just curious

Comment: This syntax is specific to PostgreSQL. If successful, it would create a function `SLEEP` that calls the stdlib `sleep` function (on a Linux system) and invoke it to sleep for 32 seconds, and would thus constitute a (rather primitive) denial of service attack. Alternatively, since this is an error on recent versions of Postgres (you can't apply `AND` to integers) it would detect if creating the function is possible, which would itself be valuable information to launch more sophisticated attacks.